# Pass the value from the iteration to the function parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I’m new to angular js and I want to do this. I have code like this:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="element in awesomeThings">
    <td ng-click="getServiceDetails()">
        <a href="#">
            {{element}}
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

In the `ng-repeat` I want to bind a `ng-click` for the html dom elements like:

```
<td ng-click="getServiceDetails()">
```

The function `getServiceDetails()` takes one parameter, which is present in the `element['id']`. How can pass this value to `getServiceDetails()` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty straightforward, you are doing this right and pretty typical:

```
<td ng-click="getServiceDetails(element.id)">
```

You can of course pass entire object as well:

```
<td ng-click="getServiceDetails(element)">
```

or even not pass anything and use `this` context inside of `getServiceDetails` function, which would point to current child scope. In this case you simply use `this.element.id`, etc.